# How to prove that $f(x) = x^2_i$ is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m \longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ denoted by $f(x) = x^n_i$, for $i \in \{1,2,\dots,m\}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, both fixed. So, let $x, h \in \mathbb{R}^m$, where $h \not = 0$. Then we have
\begin{align}
f(x+h) - f(x) &= (x_i - h_i)^n - x^n_i\\
&= \sum_{j = 0}^n{\binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}_ih^j_i} - x^n_i\\
&= \sum_{j = 1}^n{\binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}_ih^j_i}\\
&= nx^{n-1}h_i + \sum_{j = 2}^n{\binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}_ih^j_i}.
\end{align}
So, basically, we have to prove that
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sum_{j = 2}^n{\binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}_ih^j_i}}{\|h\|} = 0.$$
I tried to manipulate the following expression
$$\left|\frac{\sum_{j = 2}^n{\binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}_ih^j_i}}{\|h\|}\right|$$
but no success. Is there any hint or strategy to help me?

Comment: You can reduce the problem to showing that $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h_i^2}{\|h\|} = 0$.

Comment: I didn't understand why @jMdA. Can You be more especifc? Thx

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, the way to go really is to show that
$$\lim_{h\to0}\left|\frac{\sum_{j = 2}^n{\binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}_ih^j_i}}{\|h\|}\right|=0.$$
To this end, you just have to use the triangle inequality and the fact that $\vert h_i\vert\leq\Vert h\Vert$ for components $h_i$ of $h$. This will give you
$$\left|\frac{\sum_{j = 2}^n{\binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}_ih^j_i}}{\|h\|}\right|
\leq\frac{1}{\Vert h\Vert}\sum_{j=2}^n\binom{n}{j}\vert x_i\vert^{n-j}\vert h_i\vert^j
\leq\frac{1}{\Vert h\Vert}\sum_{j=2}^n\binom{n}{j}\vert x_i\vert^{n-j}\Vert h\Vert^j,$$

where every term in the sum in the last upper bound is at least quadratic in $\Vert h\Vert$, so after cancelling $\frac{1}{\Vert h\Vert}$, every term is at least linear in $\Vert h\Vert$. You can use this to prove that the limit is in fact $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x_i^n.$$

You want to show that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial x_i^n}{\partial x_i} = n x_i^{n-1}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial x_i^2}{\partial x_j} = 0, \quad (i\ne j).$$

The first partial derivative is computed just like an ordinary derivative.  The other expression should also be clear.

Comment: But I have to prove that $f: \mathbb{R}^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable just using the definition: $f$ is differentiable in $x$ if there is a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a function $r$
$$f(x+h) - f(x) = T \cdot h + r(h),$$
where, $r(h)/\|h\| \rightarrow 0$, if $h \to 0$.

Comment: Well, using you definition, you need $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h_i}{ \sqrt{h_1^2+\cdots h_m^2}} =1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h_i^2}{ \sqrt{h_1^2+\cdots h_m^2}} =0.$

Comment: The second one follows from $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{ \sum h_i^2}{\sqrt{\sum h_i^2}}=0.$

Answer (score 0):

You have shown that $$f(x+h)-f(x)=nx^{n-1}h_i + \sum_{j = 2}^n{\binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}_ih^j_i}=nx^{n-1} h_i + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} x^{n-2} h_i^2 + \text{higher order terms}.$$

So, now take $T=\pmatrix{0 & 0 & \cdots & \underbrace{n x^{n-1}}_{i^{\text{th}} term} & \cdots & 0}$ and $r(h)=  \frac{n(n-1)}{2} x^{n-2}  h_i^2+\text{h.o.t.}$

In the comment to another answer we showed that $\frac{r(h)}{||h||}\to 0.$